# How to pass parameter to widget?

Tags: android, parameters, widget

I'm developing a widget and I have basic question here.

When user click on the widget. It will go to config page. I use PendingIntent here.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyConfig.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.MyWidget, pendingIntent);
```

On the config page then, I have some business logic here and I want to pass the result which is Object back to update widget.

I use codes below to force an update to widget

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(MyConfig.this);
int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(MyConfig.this, MyActivity.class));
if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
    new MyActivity().onUpdate(MyConfig.this, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
};
```

How is the appropriate technique to do it?
Where I should put the Object parameter so I can access it on MyActivity class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using sharedPreferences?

Comment: I don't really know, but in my opinion this is a good start :) Did you read Android Developer tutorials?